# Android ContentProvider to access photos on phone

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to write an Android ContentProvider to interface images (JPGs) on my phone. The fields I'd like to get out might be FILENAME TEXT, CREATED_DATE DATE, MODIFIED_DATE DATE, IMAGE BLOB (for starters). What I'm trying to make is a simple gallery app, where a master activity shows thumbnails in a GridView, and a detail activity shows one image + some meta data. Maybe even showing the EXIF tags (if any) in the JPG file.

I've followed an example in a Udacity course on Android apps, but there the ContentProvider is against the SQLite database on the phone. So everything boils down to actual SQL, which "fits" perfectly with Cursors and queries. I'm having a difficult time applying this to something non-SQL, like -- in this case -- a set of files.

I know there's a standard ContentProvider MediaStore which can (should) be used to access photos and videos, but I want to (and need to) design my own CP. However, I don't know where to begin. My understanding so far is to write a class PhotoProvider extends ContentProvider, following the model of [WeatherProvider](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/tree/6.10-update-map-intent/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/data). But what about the Contract and DBHelper classes, what is the analog of those?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Btw, I am reading [Creating a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html). It's just that the photos are really not data "belonging" to my app... So, does it even make sense to write my own ContentProvider to access photos, or does that amount to re-inventing the MediaStore?

Comment: I guess I might start by having MainActivity open a cursor to MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, and then connect this to the UI (gridview) by writing a custom adapter.